# Optimize jquery datatables advanced row grouping

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, datatables

I'm new using the jquery datatables plugin, it's great, but i need to make row grouping and i make my own solution, but isn't optimal, so i wanna ask for advice/tips because the app blocks when i try to use the column filter and takes to long to load (i already optimize the mysql query).

i'm using cakephp 2.3 
this is my pendientes.ctp file 
it looks like this
[image: Pendientes de cobro with row grouping]

```
<?php
    $this->assign('icono', 'ico-files');
    $this->assign('titulo', 'Facturas Pendientes de COBRO');

?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create( array('inputDefaults' => array('label' => false,'div' => false))); ?>
<div class="row-fluid">
&nbsp;
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="data-fluid">
            <table class="table table-hover fpTableFVCP2 lcnp" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="elim">Cliente</th>                       
                        <th width="6%">Fecha</th>
                        <th>#</th>                      
                        <th>Moneda</th>
                        <th>Monto Total</th>
                        <th>Saldo</th>                      
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <thead>
                    <tr class="filtros_busqueda">
                        <td class="elim"><input type="text" name="search_cliente" placeholder="Filtrar" class="search_init"></td>                       
                        <td><input type="text" name="search_numero" placeholder="Filtrar" class="search_init"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="search_fecha" id="date-range" placeholder="Filtrar" class="search_init"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="search_moneda" id="date-range" placeholder="Filtrar" class="search_init"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="search_monto" placeholder="Filtrar" class="search_init"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="search_saldo" placeholder="Filtrar" class="search_init"></td>                      
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($data as $d):?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="elim" id="ordenador"><?php echo $d['Cliente']['NombreTitular'].'('.$d['Cliente']['RazonSocial'].')';?></td>                          
                            <td><?php echo implode('/', array_reverse(explode('-', $d['ComprobantesVenta']['fecha'])));?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $this->Html->link( $d['ComprobantesVenta']['numero'], array('action' => 'edit/'.$d['ComprobantesVenta']['id'].'/'.$d['TipoComprobante']['id']));?></td>
                            <td class="monedass"><?php echo $d['Moneda']['moneda'];?></td>  
                            <td style='text-align:right;' class="montoss"><?php echo number_format ( $d['ComprobantesVenta']['monto_total'], 2, ',', '');?></td>
                            <td style='text-align:right;' class="saldoss"><?php echo number_format ( $d['ComprobantesVenta']['saldo'], 2, ',', '');?></td>                                                                                                                                          
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </tbody>

            </table>

            <?php
                if (!empty($data))
                {
                    foreach ($data as $d):
                    ?>
                        <!--ACA COMIENZA EL DETALLE DE LA TABLA-->
                        <div id="row<?php echo $d['ComprobantesVenta']['id'];?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
                        style="margin-left:300px; width:900px; height:300px;">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                                <h4 id="myModalLabel">Datos del Comprobante <?php echo $d['TipoComprobante']['abreviacion'].'-'. $d['ComprobantesVenta']['numero']; ?></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <table class="table" cellpading="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Tipo Documento</th>
                                            <th>Art&iacute;culo</th>
                                            <th>Cantidad</th>
                                            <th>Monto</th>
                                            <th>Subtotal</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        <?php
                                            foreach ($d['ComprobantesVentaDetalle'] as $dd)
                                            {
                                                echo "<tr>";
                                                echo "<td>". $dd['tipo_documento']." - #".$dd['documento_numero']."</td>";
                                                echo "<td>". $dd['Articulo']['0']['Articulo']['nombre']."</td>";
                                                echo "<td style='text-align:right;'>". number_format ( $dd['cantidad'], 2, ',', '')."</td>";
                                                echo "<td style='text-align:right;'>". $d['Moneda']['moneda']. " " . number_format ( $dd['monto'], 2, ',', '.')."</td>";
                                                echo "<td style='text-align:right;'>". $d['Moneda']['moneda']. " " . number_format ( $dd['monto'] * $dd['cantidad'], 2, ',', '.')."</td>";
                                                echo '</tr>';
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cerrar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--FIN DEL DETALLE DE LA TABLA-->
                    <?php
                    endforeach;
                }
                ?>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    columnas_sort = [ null,  { "sType": "date-uk"},  null, null,  { "sType": "currency"}, { "sType": "currency"}];

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".filtros_busqueda").show();  

        if ($(".fpTableFVCP2").length > 0)
        {
            var fCTable = $(".fpTableFVCP2").dataTable({bSort: true,
                bAutoWidth: true,
                "iDisplayLength": 50, "aLengthMenu": [ 50, 100], // can be removed for basic 10 items per page
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                "oTableTools": {
                    "sSwfPath": "../js/plugins/datatables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                    "aButtons": [
                        {
                            "sExtends": "print",
                            "sButtonText": "Imprimir",  
                        },
                        {
                            "sExtends": "pdf",
                            "sButtonText": "Guardar PDF",
                            "sPdfMessage": "Documento",
                            "sPdfOrientation": "landscape"  

                        },
                        {
                            "sExtends": "xls",
                            "sButtonText": "Guardar Excel"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "aoColumns": columnas_sort,
                //"aoColumnDefs": [{"bSortable": false, "aTargets": []},], version original
                "aoColumnDefs": [{"bSortable": true, "aTargets": []},], //daniel 01062015
                //agregando callback daniel 01062015
                "order": [[ 0, 'current' ]],
                "fnDrawCallback": function ( oSettings ) {
            var api = this.oApi;
            var anNodes = $('#ordenador', api._fnGetTrNodes( oSettings ));
            var anNodes2 = api._fnGetTrNodes( oSettings );  

    var total=$(anNodes).length;
     var last=null;
     var band=true;
     var cont=0;
     var acum=1;     
     var saldos=0;
     var monedas="$";
     var pesos=0;
     var dolares=0;
     var euros=0;
     $( anNodes).each( function (index){
                    cont=cont+1;
                    acum=acum+1;

                if (last !== $(this).text()){
                    if (band){
                    //   console.log($(this).text()); 
                    $('#ordenador',anNodes2).eq( index ).closest('tr').before(
                        '<tr class="group"><td class="fondos" colspan="5">'+ $(this).text() +'</td></tr> '
                    );
                    band=false;
                      }
                      else{

                    cont=cont-1;
                    var auxiliar=last.split("(",1);
                    $('#ordenador',anNodes2).eq( index ).closest('tr').before(
                        '<tr class="totales"><td  colspan="5"> El total del cliente ' + auxiliar + ' es ' + saldos +' '+ monedas + '</td></tr> <tr class="group"><td class="fondos" colspan="5">'+ $(this).text() +'</td></tr> '
                    );

                          saldos=0;  
                      }
                      if(total  < acum){  
                        cont=cont+1;

                monedas=$('#ordenador',anNodes2).eq( index ).siblings('.monedass').text();
                        saldos=saldos+parseFloat($('#ordenador',anNodes2).sort().eq( index ).siblings('.saldoss').text());  
                          if (monedas=="$"){
                    pesos=pesos+saldos;

                }
                if (monedas=="U$S"){
                    dolares=dolares+saldos;                 
                }
                if(monedas=="Euros"){
                    euros=euros+saldos;                 
                }
                    var auxiliar2=$(this).text().split("(",1);    
                    $('#ordenador',anNodes2).sort().eq( total-1 ).closest('tr').after(
                        '<tr class="totales"><td  colspan="5"> El total del cliente  ' + auxiliar2 + ' es '+saldos +' '+monedas+'</td></tr> <tr class="totales"><td  colspan="5"> El total general en $ es ' + pesos + '</td></tr> <tr class="totales"><td  colspan="5"> El total general en U$S es ' + dolares + '</td></tr><tr class="totales"><td  colspan="5"> El total general en Euros es ' + euros + '</td></tr> '
                    );


                      }
                    //  console.log(acum);
                    last=$(this).text();
                }
                monedas=$('#ordenador',anNodes2).eq( index ).siblings('.monedass').text();
                saldos=saldos+parseFloat($('#ordenador',anNodes2).sort().eq( index ).siblings('.saldoss').text());
                if (monedas=="$"){
                    pesos=pesos+saldos;

                }
                if (monedas=="U$S"){
                    dolares=dolares+saldos;                 
                }
                if(monedas=="Euros"){
                    euros=euros+saldos;                 
                }


     });

        $(".fondos").css("background-color","#ddd !important");
        $(".elim").hide();


        } //fin callback                01062015



            });

        //$(".eliminar").remove();  
            //agregando el order 01062015 para que cuando se haga click en el area ordene todo


    $(".DTTT_button_print").on('click',function(){ 
        $(".filtros_busqueda").hide();      
        window.print();
    } );


            //fin de order 01062015
    $("thead input").keyup(function () {


                fCTable.fnFilter(HtmlEncode(this.value), $("thead input").index(this));
            });



            $("thead input").each(function (i) {
                if (this.value != "") {
                    fCTable.fnFilter(HtmlEncode(this.value), $("thead input").index(this));
                    //fCTable.fnDraw();
                }
            });


            $("thead input").focus(function () {
                if (this.className == "search_init")
                {
                    this.className = "";
                    fCTable.fnDraw();
                }
            });

            $("thead input").blur(function (i) {
                if (this.value == "")
                {
                    this.className = "search_init";
                    fCTable.fnDraw();
                }
            });



        }
    });


</script>
```

Comment: btw there are only 700 records so i believe that doesn't need ajax or server side, it has to be my code that isn't optimal.

Answer (score 0):

esto: 
     `var total=$(anNodes).length;
     var last=null;
     var band=true;
     var cont=0;
     var acum=1;

     var saldos=0;
     var monedas="$";
     var pesos=0;
     var dolares=0;
     var euros=0;`

lo cambias a esto:

```
var obj = {
    total: $(anNodes).length,
    last: null,
    band: true,
    cont: 0,
    acum: 1,     
    saldos: 0,
    monedas: "$",
    pesos: 0,
    dolares: 0,
    euros: 0
};
```